# passing an argument to a method called from clicking a button

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

[image]I have the tree view in the attached picture

Let's say this is a tree view on model A

I want to selct one line and then click a button that creates a record in another model, say model B, using the selected line as a blueprint (for some values)

Or, maybe, add a button in the tree view, so tha I just have to click the right button, without the double passgae select/press button

How do I achieve that ?

I could use an example

I can call a method from a button

But how do I get acces to the selected record in the code ?

Comment: What would be your preferred way: an action in the action menu/dropdown or a button on every row in the list? An action will have the advantage to have a multi row creation for model b. You can ofcourse implement both ways at the same time.

Comment: The preferred way would be a button on every row

but also selecting a bunch of rows and then calling an action from a menu would  be ok

@CZoellner

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Server Action (in debug mode under the Technical menu) and execute Python code. The records selected in the list view will be stored in the `records` variable.

```
# records is a recordset of model.a
for record in records:
    if record.x_some_field:
        # create a new model.b record
        env['model.b'].create({...})
```